# Getting an EntrySet in a MultiMap

Tags: java, multimap

I have a MultiMap and need the best possible way to get an EntrySet of a MultiMap using one of the values in the list.  Right now, I'm iterating through the entry set of the whole map and checking if the value of the list contains my needed values.  This works for a limited number of inputs on the map, but its now turned into 800ms - 1 second work, which just wont cut it.  Thanks for the help in advanced.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiMap multi = new MultiHashMap();
        multi.put("Key1", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" })));
}
```

I want to be able to get Key1, Value1, Value2 and Value3 by only inputting Value1 and Value2 as arguments

Also, if it's any help, this is from a cache after reading a data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Edited to allow for group of values to be tested simultaneously]*

*[Edited again now that the question has been clarified]*

This implementation avoids explicit loops, and is written in a more functional manner using Guava extensions:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class TestIt {

    public static Iterable<Entry<Integer, String>> getEntrySetsForValues(
            Multimap<Integer, String> fromMap, final Collection<String> values) {
        return Iterables.filter(fromMap.entries(),
                new Predicate<Entry<Integer, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean apply(Entry<Integer, String> arg0) {
                        return values.contains(arg0.getValue());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

A test program:

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

public class Test {

    static Multimap<Integer, String> x = HashMultimap.create();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x.put(1, "a");
        x.put(1, "b");
        x.put(2, "d");
        x.put(3, "e");
        x.put(3, "f");
        x.put(4, "a");
        x.put(5, "b");
        x.put(5, "c");

        System.out.println(TestIt.getEntrySetsForValues(x,
                Sets.newHashSet("a", "c")));
    }
}
```

The output:

[1=a, 4=a, 5=c]

I'd be curious to know how inefficient it is.

Comment: This is almost amazing, but the only problem is I need it so that the entry has both defined values, not either or.  But this is amazing (haven't tested run times, efficiency much yet tho)

Comment: Thanks.  You can easily modify this to give you the entries, or just the keys, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Apache Common's [Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/)? they have a [multimap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) implementation that might help you, in particular the `containsValue` method.

Assuming that there are no duplicate elements in the values, you could use a Set for holding the multi-values and speed-up the search. Just an (untested) idea, something like this:

```
public static <K, V> Map.Entry<K, Set<V>> getEntry(Map<K,Set<V>> map, Set<V> vals) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, Set<V>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        boolean found = true;
        for (V val : vals) {
            if (!entry.getValue().contains(val)) {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found)
            return entry;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have, but my problem is I need to get the whole collection, and the key, using around 4 values of the collection.  Of course, the only thing I can think of is iteration.

Comment: This is good, but I'm already doing around the same thing.  There's too many values for an iteration (over 10k)

Comment: Check to see if my above implementation meets your requirements: it receives a multimap and a set of searched values and returns the pair key,values

Comment: I know it probably will work, but what I'm worried about is the time and efficiency of it.  I think I found something, thanks a lot for the anyway tho!